# Hibernate getting all throw Nullpointerexcepetion ina Object relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception, many-to-one

i have 2 classes, the Person class that have a ManyToOne relationship with Address class. When i trying to get the persons, the address object have null elements inside, why happens this? the lazy configuration dont works? I can save a Person Object with the Address in cascade.

Here is my code:

Person class:

```java
public class Person  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int idPerson;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String dni;
    private Date dateBirth;
    private String cellPhone;
    private String landPhone;
    private String email;
    private String discr;
    private Address address ;
   
    public Person() {
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

My Address class:

```java
public class Address  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int idAddress;
    private City city;
    private String street;
    private String number;
    private Integer apartament;
    private int level;

    public Address() {
    }
    //getters an setters
}
```

My two mapping files:

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.efix.model.enterprise.Address" table="address" schema="public">
        <id name="idAddress" type="int">
            <column name="id_address" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="city" class="com.efix.model.enterprise.City" cascade="all" lazy="false">
            <column name="id_city" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="street" type="string">
            <column name="street" length="60" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="number" type="string">
            <column name="number" length="6" />
        </property>
        <property name="apartament" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="apartament" />
        </property>
        <property name="level" type="int">
            <column name="level" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Above is the address maping and this is my peopel mapping:

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.efix.model.enterprise.Person" table="person" schema="public">
        <id name="idPerson" type="int">
            <column name="id_person" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <discriminator column="discr" type="string"/>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="40" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="surname" type="string">
            <column name="surname" length="40" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dni" type="string">
            <column name="dni" length="40" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateBirth" type="date">
            <column name="date_birth" length="13" />
        </property>
        <property name="cellPhone" type="string">
            <column name="cell_phone" length="20"/>
        </property>
        <property name="landPhone" type="string">
            <column name="land_phone" length="20"/>
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="25" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one class="com.efix.model.enterprise.Address" name="address">
            <column name="id_address" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <!-- Subclase Empleado -->
        <subclass name="com.efix.model.enterprise.Employee" discriminator-value="Employee">
            <property name="admissionDate" type="date">
                <column name="admission_date" length="13" />
            </property>
            <property name="outDate" type="date">
                <column name="out_date" length="13" />
            </property>
            <property name="position" type="string">
                <column name="position" length="40" />
            </property>
        </subclass>

        <!-- Sublcase cliente -->
        <subclass name="com.efix.model.enterprise.Client" discriminator-value="Client">
            <property name="notes" type="string">
                <column name="notes" />
            </property>
        </subclass>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My NullPointerException throws in this block of code:

```java
ClientServiceImpl serviceImpl = new ClientServiceImpl();
for (Client cli : serviceImpl.findAll()) {
    System.out.println(cli.getAddress().getNumber());
```

Comment: Please, post the entire stacktrace of the error and highlight the line of code firing the error. Moreover what is `ClientServiceImpl`?

Comment: The exception is this: Oct 18, 2013 9:45:53 AM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
SEVERE: javax.el.ELException: /enterprises/persons/client.xhtml @236,141 value="#{clientController.selectedClient.address.number}": Error reading 'number' on type com.efix.model.enterprise.Address_$$_javassist_0

The ClientServiceImpl, is the class that call to the DAO to save the data in the DB. I debug the project and i have the reference to the Address object null.

Comment: Stupid question, but I need to be sure ... Does this person have a valid (not null) Address (I mean into the DB)?

Comment: The field have a not null attribute in DB, you have an idea why it can be?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for yours reply!! My error was in a expression inside a . I was references to a non existed property!!

Comment: Happy to know you fixed your problem. Ciao!